# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [XXX.title] on this ManagedType

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

In my front end part, I have a table in which I can sort its columns (asc,desc). These columns represent attributes of two entities `Activity` and `Objective` which have `@OneToOne` relation.
The front end sends to the web service the name of the attribute subject of sort. when the attribute's name equal to `objective.title`, I had this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [objective.title] on this ManagedType [entity.Activity]
```

Below the code of two entities :

class Activity.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACTIVITY")
public class Activity{ 
     
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REFID") 
    private Long refid;
     
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRINCIPAL_OBJECTIVE")
    private Objective objective;
    // getters + setters
}
```

class Objective.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OBJECTIVE")
public class Objective{

@Column(name = "TITLE")
private String title;

@Column(name = "TYPE")
private Short objectiveType;

// getters + setters
}
```

Comment: what do you mean here `sends to the web service the name of the attribute subject of sort`

Comment: @Boug the web service receive from the front end part the name of column to be sorted (sort asc or desc), for example, the front end part send `refid` (name of attribute in Activity class), in this case I didn't have a problem

Comment: this is not a frontend issue. This is a backend issue. Figure what is triggered in the backend. then post your backend relative code and the stacktrace. That way we can help you out

Comment: thank you for your reply, I know that's a backend issue, so I published the two entities, I guess that's a problem of annotation between the two entities.

Comment: @mak_doni I do not see @Id field of your `Objective` entity. Do you have it?

Comment: @SternK yes I have it, I wrote the important fields.